# Android widgets is not showing its attributes Suggestions when i going to write

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-layout-weight

Android Weight is not showing its attributes when I try write its property. But it works if write. Now I want to watch a suggestion when I write. how can I solve this problem? Check image for more clarity.

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**[UPDATE]
i alse add my app/build.gradle file**
i restart my android studio but i face the same problem. i create a new project the problem belongs there.

My app/build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.rocketechit.officemanagementapp"
          minSdkVersion 16
          targetSdkVersion 28
         versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'

    //Butter knife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'

    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

    //picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    //circle image view
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
//custom calender
    implementation 'sun.bob:mcalendarview:1.0.0'

    //scanner

    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: start typing as **app:weight** and you will see the suggestion

Comment: @RahulKhurana i want to see the suggestion when i going to write the attribute(See the image). it's worked some hours ago but suddenly it's not working.i restart my android studio but not solve. have you other solutions ?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Select Invalidate and Restart
```

Try the above code it will clean up all the caches from android studio. Hope it will works :)

**EDIT**

Delete **.idea** folder and all **.iml** files from the project, then restart **Android Studio** and **rebuild gradle** will work in this case. And don't forget to **Invalidate Caches / Restart** as well after deletion

If the above case still doesn't work for you then you need to delete **system** files from android studio

**yourPathToDrive:/.AndroidStudio3.3/system**

Comment: @ImranSk Ok don't worry. Just put your **app/build.gradle** file in the question

Comment: @ImranSk as i can see you are mostly using beta version libraries. try switching to stable version of each release and let me know

Comment: maybe it's not the problem, because it worked some hours ago,that time xml suggest me what i write. after push the project on git and i pull it again then it's not showing the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just navigate to your android studio installation directory, i.e,

yourDrive:/.AndroidStudio3.4/system

first close android studio, if its running.

then delete the cache folder in system

Then start Android Studio again. Done.

i am using android studio 3.5